# LARAVEL request get is always getting full url instead of parameter name

Tags: php, laravel, controller, request

I wrote this code below

```
dd($_GET);
```

or

```
dd($request->all())
```

But always get array with full url

[image: In controller]

instead this array

[image: In php file]

But when i just put "&" char. This is the output.

[image]

home/public_html as public folder on laravel.
home/private_document as app root laravel.

Check this out Check this out https://ekinerja.lebakkab.go.id/test?month=1

Comment: And what do you get when you use Laravel's request helper `dd(request()->all())`? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request

Comment: I just tried. Same value :(

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: Apache2. Check this out https://ekinerja.lebakkab.go.id/test?month=1

Comment: home/public_html as public folder on laravel.
home/private_document as app root laravel.

Comment: I suspect your document root isn't set up correctly. It should be pointing to _index.php_, not _test.php_. Start from the beginning and make sure you have all your configuration setup correctly - https://laravel.com/docs/master#configuration

Comment: `Please ensure, like the configuration below, your web server directs all requests to your application's public/index.php file. You should never attempt to move the index.php file to your project's root, as serving the application from the project root will expose many sensitive configuration files to the public Internet:` - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#server-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `$_GET` in Laravel.

Try using `request()->month` or `$request->query('month')` instead.

Comment: the value is the same. Therefore, I try to use dd ($ _ GET) and ($ reques-> all ()) to get whatever variables are obtained and the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this `$request->get('month')`

Answer (score 0):

*You can get month value using this*

```
$month = $request->get('month');
```

Comment: Its not worked.
The output is
"//{route}/?month"=>"1"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the 'Content-Type' in Header's request with the value 'application/json'.

if you are using insomnia you can edit this easily:

[insomnia config example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fMrj.png)